# I'm looking for the StreamSend.h library for use in Arduino/ESP8266 serial communications using struct

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, serial-data, struct, stream

I've come across an interesting yet old article within StackExchange which has great examples of sending structured variables over serial communications. The library StreamSend.h and it's source code no longer exist on this site and I'm finding it difficult to track down. The examples shown look good and I'd like to use them in my application. My application is communication of large amounts of data between an ESP8266 and a Arduino UNO (both are combined on the same PCBA) via UART serial.

This is the article I'm referring to:

[Sending Large Amounts of Serial Data](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/203/sending-large-amounts-of-serial-data)

Can somebody send me the StreamSend.h library please or alternative methods for sending large amounts of data over serial (by large amounts of data I mean reading/writing say 10 to 20 variables of various data types so struct would suit well). Thank you.

Regards,

Brian

Comment: The code is in the article you linked to - right under `StreamSend Class`. Copy that code, save it as `StreamSend.h` or `StreamSend.hpp`.

Comment: Thanks romkey. I have created the StreamSend.h file and the ESP8266 and Arduino programs both compile.I send the struct from the ESP to the Arduino using the same code in this blog for send and receiving a struct. I can see on the serial monitor that the ESP appears to be sending data but the Arduino is quiet. I've noted the StreamSend.h file has #include "Arduino.h" but no reference to ESP8266. So could this be an issue?

Comment: I'd suggest asking that in a new question.